# LWC - Bypass Field-Level Security using Lightning-Input-Field?

Tags: lightning-web-components, field-level-security, lightning-recordeditform, lightning-inputfield

Is it possible to create an LWC input form that bypasses field-level security, while still leveraging the powerful UI brought by `<lightning-input-field>`?

Im creating a generic filter component so admin can create filter criteria for any configured SObject and any of its fields. On submit, `preventDefault()` is used to stop the usual record edit/creation that comes along with a `<lightning-record-edit-form>`, since I don't need to save these filters in the backend. The user's input is extracted and used by the controller, and eventually dispatched in an event for parent components to handle.

The `<lightning-input-field>` is useful because it automatically handles input UI, e.g. if given Contact.Birthdate, it will automatically render a datepicker element.

However, even though the form doesn't perform DML thanks to `preventDefault()`, a user without CREATE permission still cannot use the form (they gets a toast error: `Record is not createable`).

Is it possible to instruct the form to ignore field-level security, or some other way around it?

HTML:

```
<lightning-record-edit-form
        object-api-name={objectType}
        onsubmit={handleSubmit}>

    <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>

    <lightning-combobox
            label="Operator"
            value={operator}
            options={operatorOptions}></lightning-combobox>

    <lightning-input-field
            field-name={fieldName}
            value={value}></lightning-input-field>

    <lightning-button type="submit" label="Submit"></lightning-button>

</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class FilterController extends LightningElement {

    @api objectType;
    @api operator;
    @api fieldName;
    @api value;

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let inputValue = event.detail.fields[this.fieldName];
        let inputOperator = event.detail.fields["Operator"];
        this.doSave(inputValue, inputOperator);
    }

    get operatorOptions() {
        return ...;
    }

    doSave(value, operator) {
        // Dispatches an event for parent component
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not possible. Instead, you'd have to use [getObjectInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_object_info) and render your own UI.

Answer (score 0):

If your user has edit permission on the object, you can simply pass `record-id={recordId}` to the `<lightning-record-edit-form>` tag and it works. LDS will consider it is for update and render `<lightning-record-edit-form>` properly. After this, you can keep using `preventDefault()` in js file and do whatever you need with the values user entered.

The only challenge here is getting `recordId`, If you are using your component on any object's lightning record page by adding `@recordId` to js file you can get record id. If your component is generic hard code some random record id from the `objectType` you are passing to  `<lightning-record-edit-form>`.